# Validation date between Textview and String

Tags: java, android

I'm doing my first application on Android, it consists of a "To do Task". My problem is when I want to check the text of my `TextView`, which contains the date (array of strings), with the date on which the information is saved. This if I do to run the check never works.

```
// Write date in Array
SimpleDateFormat formatdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
String[] date = new String[6];
for(int i = 0; i < 6;i++){
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE  , 1);
    date[i] = formatdate.format(calendar.getTime());
}

tvdate2.setText(date[0]); // 16-03-2021
...

// When clicking on the button, it checks and then displays the corresponding information
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {                
        String test ="16-03-2021";
        if (tvdate2.getText().toString() == test){
            testing.setText("It works!!");
        }                
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used java in a while, but to compare two strings you would need to use `.equals()`. What you probably want is:

```
if (tvdate2.getText().toString().equals(test)) {
```